# Finding Audio and Text between two <td> tags Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am working with this website http://www.nemoapps.com/phrasebooks/hebrew.

And for every td element, for example, I would like to get the first mp3 audio file `/audio/mp3/HEBFND1_1395.mp3` and then get the hebrew text `<strong>שרה שרה שיר שמח, שיר שמח שרה שרה</strong>` and the pronunciation `<strong>Sara shara shir sameaĥ, shir sameaĥ shara sara</strong>`

The following code kind of accomplishes what I am trying to get but not quite there.

```
<source src="/audio/ogg/HEBFND1_1395.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</source></source>
[]
[<div class="target1" lang="he"><strong>\u05e9\u05e8\u05d4 \u05e9\u05e8\u05d4 \u05e9\u05d9\u05e8 \u05e9\u05de\u05d7, \u05e9\u05d9\u05e8 \u05e9\u05de\u05d7 \u05e9\u05e8\u05d4 \u05e9\u05e8\u05d4</strong></div>, <div class="target2" lang="he-Latn"><strong>Sara shara shir samea\u0125, shir samea\u0125 shara sara</strong></div>, <div class="translation">Tongue Twister: Sara sings a happy song, a happy song Sara is singing</div>]
```

This is a sample output I get. But I need to get into `source` and `<div><strong>` to retrieve the information I want.

The following is the code I used.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib

_url = "http://www.nemoapps.com/phrasebooks/hebrew"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(_url), features="lxml")
_trs = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in _trs:
    cells = tr.find_all('td', recursive=False)
    for cell in cells:
        audio = cell.find_all('audio')
        div = cell.find_all('div')
        for a in audio:
            source = a.find_all('source', type='audio/mpeg')
            for s in source:
                print(s)
        print(div)
    print("++++++++")
```

Please let me know if there is any other efficient way to accomplish this. Thanks,

Comment: Each tr is rather structured.  BS4 allows you to find these without cycling down into each one with the loops you're doing.  Each tr contains the audio (you can do a find instead of a find_all as there's never multiple audio/mpeg typed ones). Also, all target1 class, he lang divs are the hebrew, he-Latn lang/target2 are the phonetic, and class translation is the english.  You should be able to define each of these out to a variable.  EACH tr has exactly 1 of these; which means you can use find and no need for the 3 nested for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find BeautifulSoup hard to use and byzantine, especially when it comes to finding elements by anything but the simplest rules.

The `lxml` module functions well with HTML sources and offers XPath support, which means finding elements is *much* easier and much more flexible.

I also prefer using the `requests` module over the very bare-bones urllib.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

resp = requests.get("http://www.nemoapps.com/phrasebooks/hebrew")

htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(resp.text, htmlparser)

for tr in tree.xpath('.//table[@class="nemocards"]/tr'):
    data = {
        'source': tr.xpath('string(.//source[@type="audio/mpeg"]/@src)'),
        'hebrew': tr.xpath('normalize-space(.//div[@lang="he"])'),
        'latin': tr.xpath('normalize-space(.//div[@lang="he-Latn"])'),
        'translation': tr.xpath('normalize-space(.//div[@class="translation"])'),
    }
    print(data)
```

Notes:

- `string()` is an XPath function that gets a node's text content (whether that's an attribute node or an element node makes no difference).
- `normalize-space()` does the same, but additionally it trims excess whitespace.
- When called without such a string conversion (i.e. like `tr.xpath('.//div[@lang="he"]')`, you'd get a (possibly empty) list of matching elements. Since your goal is to extract the element's text content, and this task is harder to do in Python code, using the XPath string functions right away makes your life much easier - they will simply return a (possibly empty) string.
- `.//table[@class="nemocards"]` will only match when the table's class attribute is *precisely* "nemocards". For partial matches, something like `.//table[contains(@class, "nemocards")]` could be used.

Output is like this:

```
{'source': '/audio/mp3/HEBFND1_0001.mp3', 'hebrew': 'שלום', 'latin': 'Shalom', 'translation': 'Hello'}
```